# Can we construct two sets and functions for the given conditions?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, vector-spaces

Can we construct two sets $A$, $B$ and two invertible functions (one to one) $f_A \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $f_B\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the following conditions are satisfied?
The conditions are $A\subset\mathbb C^n$, $B\subset\mathbb C^n$, $A,B$ are dense, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $\forall a\in A$, $b\in B$, $f_A(a+b)=f_A(a)$, $f_B(a+b)=f_B(b)$. Moreover the sets $A,B$ and the ranges of $f_A$, $f_B$ cannot lose dimensions. Dimension here means the number of vectors in the basis. i.e., $\text{dimension}(A)=n$, $\text{dimension}(B)=n$, $\text{dimension}(f_A)=n$ and $\text{dimension}(f_B)=n$.

P.S.

Without the condition on dimension we can find linear functions $f_A$, $f_B$ such that they are in each others null space. For me the complication is to preserve the dimension and make the sets dense. That is I can think of losing dimensions and keeping dense or losing dense and keeping dimension. Because building two finite sets $A,B$ with above conditions and dimension $n$ is possible.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: So $f_A=f_B=0$ is not allowed? You wrote that the dimensions of $A$ and $B$ are $n$. Do you mean the dimensions of $f_A(A)$ and $f_B(B)$ are $n$?

Comment: Do you mean "there exist $a\in A$, $b\in B$, ..." or "for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$, ..."?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It is for all. Thank you.

Comment: @WillNelson The functions has to be invertible. Both the sets and the functions have same dimension. I added it to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the $\mathbb Q$-vector space $\mathbb C$ pick a complement $V$   of $U:=\mathbb Q[i]$. Then $U$ and $V$ are dense in $\mathbb C$ and $U\cap V=\{0\}$.
Let $A=U\setminus\{0\}$, $B=V\setminus\{0\}$ and for $z\in \mathbb C$ write $z=u+v$ with $u\in U$, $v\in V$ and let $f_A(z)=u$, $f_B(z)=v$.

Comment: Thank you. By $\mathbb{Q}$ I guess you mean the rational numbers. So $A$ is rational and $B$ is irrational and $z$ is in real field. So how can I know there are no $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$ such that $z=u_1+v_1=u_2+v_2$?